# When should I use jQuery deferred's "then" method and when should I use the "pipe" method?

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, jquery-deferred, decoupling, jquery-chaining

jQuery's [`Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) has two functions which can be used to implement asynchronous chaining of functions:

## [`then()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/)

> **`deferred.then( doneCallbacks, failCallbacks ) Returns: Deferred`**
>
> **doneCallbacks** A function, or array of functions, called when the Deferred is resolved.
>   **failCallbacks** A function, or array of functions, called when the Deferred is rejected.

## [`pipe()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/)

> **`deferred.pipe( [doneFilter] [, failFilter] ) Returns: Promise`**
>
> **doneFilter** An optional function that is called when the Deferred is resolved.
>   **failFilter** An optional function that is called when the Deferred is rejected.

I know `then()` has been around a little longer than `pipe()` so the latter must add some extra benefit, but what the difference precisely is eludes me. Both take pretty much the same callback parameters though they differ in name and the difference between returning a `Deferred` and returning a `Promise` seems slight.

I've read the official docs over and over but always find them too "dense" to really wrap my head around and searching has found lots of discussion of the one feature or the other but I haven't found anything that really clarifies the different pros and cons of each.

**So when is it better to use `then` and when is it better to use `pipe`?**

---

## Addition

[Felix's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9601230/527702) has really helped clarify how these two functions differ. But I wonder if there are times when the functionality of `then()` is preferable to that of `pipe()`.

It is apparent that `pipe()` is more powerful than `then()` and it seems the former can do anything the latter can do. One reason to use `then()` might be that its name reflects its role as the termination of a chain of functions processing the same data.

**But is there a use case that requires `then()`'s returning the original `Deferred` that can't be done with `pipe()` due to it returning a new `Promise`?**

Comment: I thought about this for a while, but tbh, I can't think of any use case. It might just be an overhead to create new promise objects if you don't need them (I don't know how they are chained together internally). That said, there are certainly people who have a better understanding of this than me.

Comment: Anyone interested in this question will surely be interested in Ticket #11010 on the jQuery bug tracker: **[MAKE DEFERRED.THEN == DEFERRED.PIPE LIKE PROMISE/A](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11010)**

Comment: related: [pipe() and then() documentation vs reality in jQuery 1.8](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12011925/1048572)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Since **jQuery 1.8** `.then` behaves the same as `.pipe`:

> **Deprecation Notice:** As of jQuery 1.8, the `deferred.pipe()` method is deprecated. The `deferred.then()` method, which replaces it, should be used instead.

and

> **As of jQuery 1.8**, the `deferred.then()` method returns a new promise that can filter the status and values of a deferred through a function, replacing the now-deprecated `deferred.pipe()` method.

The examples below might still be helpful to some.

---

They serve different purposes:

- `.then()` is to be used whenever you want to work with the result of the process, i.e. as the documentation says, when the deferred object is resolved or rejected. It is the same as using `.done()` or `.fail()`.
- You'd use `.pipe()` to (pre)*filter* the result somehow. The return value of a callback to `.pipe()` will be passed as argument to the `done` and `fail` callbacks. It can also return another deferred object and the following callbacks will be registered on this deferred.

  That is not the case with `.then()` (or `.done()`, `.fail()`), the return values of the registered callbacks are just ignored.

So it is not that you use *either* `.then()` *or* `.pipe()`. You *could* use `.pipe()` for the same purposes as `.then()` but the converse does not hold.

---

#### Example 1

The result of some operation is an array of objects:

```
[{value: 2}, {value: 4}, {value: 6}]
```

and you want to compute the minimum and maximum of the values. Lets assume we use two `done` callbacks:

```
deferred.then(function(result) {
    // result = [{value: 2}, {value: 4}, {value: 6}]

    var values = [];
    for(var i = 0, len = result.length; i < len; i++) {
        values.push(result[i].value);
    }
    var min = Math.min.apply(Math, values);

   /* do something with "min" */

}).then(function(result) {
    // result = [{value: 2}, {value: 4}, {value: 6}]

    var values = [];
    for(var i = 0, len = result.length; i < len; i++) {
        values.push(result[i].value);
    }
    var max = Math.max.apply(Math, values);

   /* do something with "max" */ 

});
```

In both cases you have to iterate over the list and extract the value from each object.

Wouldn't it be better to somehow extract the values beforehand so that you don't have to do this in both callbacks individually? Yes! And that's what we can use `.pipe()` for:

```
deferred.pipe(function(result) {
    // result = [{value: 2}, {value: 4}, {value: 6}]

    var values = [];
    for(var i = 0, len = result.length; i < len; i++) {
        values.push(result[i].value);
    }
    return values; // [2, 4, 6]

}).then(function(result) {
    // result = [2, 4, 6]

    var min = Math.min.apply(Math, result);

    /* do something with "min" */

}).then(function(result) {
    // result = [2, 4, 6]

    var max = Math.max.apply(Math, result);

    /* do something with "max" */

});
```

Obviously this is a made up example and there are many different (maybe better) ways to solve this problem, but I hope it illustrates the point.

---

#### Example 2

Consider Ajax calls. Sometimes you want to initiate one Ajax call after a previous one completes. One way is to make the second call inside a `done` callback:

```
$.ajax(...).done(function() {
    // executed after first Ajax
    $.ajax(...).done(function() {
        // executed after second call
    });
});
```

Now lets assume you want to decouple your code and put these two Ajax calls inside a function:

```
function makeCalls() {
    // here we return the return value of `$.ajax().done()`, which
    // is the same deferred object as returned by `$.ajax()` alone

    return $.ajax(...).done(function() {
        // executed after first call
        $.ajax(...).done(function() {
            // executed after second call
        });
    });
}
```

You'd like to use the deferred object to allow other code which calls `makeCalls` to attach callbacks for the *second* Ajax call, but

```
makeCalls().done(function() {
    // this is executed after the first Ajax call
});
```

would not have the desired effect as the second call is made inside a `done` callback and not accessible from the outside.

The solution would be to use `.pipe()` instead:

```
function makeCalls() {
    // here we return the return value of `$.ajax().pipe()`, which is
    // a new deferred/promise object and connected to the one returned
    // by the callback passed to `pipe`

    return $.ajax(...).pipe(function() {
        // executed after first call
        return $.ajax(...).done(function() {
            // executed after second call
        });
    });
}

makeCalls().done(function() {
    // this is executed after the second Ajax call
});
```

By using `.pipe()` you can now make it possible to append callbacks to the "inner" Ajax call without exposing the actual flow/order of the calls.

---

In general, deferred objects provide an interesting way to decouple your code :)

Comment: Ah yes I overlooked that `pipe` can do filtering that `then` can't do. But in Googling these topics it seems they chose to call it `pipe` rather than `filter` because the considered the filtering to be something of a bonus extra that came with it whereas `pipe` more clearly indicated its true purpose. So it seems there should be other differences besides the filtering. (Then again I admit I don't really understand the filtering feature even with your examples. Should `result values;` be `return values;` by the way?)

Comment: When I say I don't understand your examples, is it something like this: In the upper example, the two `.then()`s receive the same data in `result` which you filter each time; whereas in the lower example, the `.pipe()` removes some of the data in its `result` before passing that on as the `result` the two subsequent `.then()`s will receive?

Comment: @hippietrail: I updated my answer in the meantime and also included the other purposes of `.pipe()`. If the callback returns a deferred object, subsequent done or fail callbacks will be registered for that object. I will include another example. *edit:* regarding your second comment: yes.

Comment: So one difference is that data flows *through* `pipe()` whereas `then()` is more like a *leaf node* at the end of which you must use your data and it does not flow further on, and that despite the fact that `then()` returns a `Deferred` it is not actually used/useful? If this is right it might help to clarify to include something like `/* do something with "min"/"max" */` in each ".then() clause".

Comment: I just realized I have obviously been confusing the return values of `then()` and `pipe()` with the return values of their (anonymous) callbacks ...

Comment: No worries :) It took me some time as well to fully comprehend how deferred objects and their methods work. But once you understand it, it does not appear to be difficult anymore. I agree that the documentation could probably be written in an easier way.

Comment: Felix, you might be interested in my addittional question about whether "then" can do anything that "pipe" cannot do.

Comment: Would it be true to say that `then()` functions as a "tee" and allows you to perform two different operations on the same data, whereas `pipe()` functions just as a "pipe" and passes on a different version of the original data (by filtering or mapping it etc)? Or am I still missing something?

Comment: `That is not the case with .then() (or .done(), .fail()), the return values of the registered callbacks are just ignored.` Nope, please see the example here - http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

Comment: @coding_idiot: Yes, I'm acknowledging this at the beginning of the answer where I say that .then now behaves like .pipe. The rest of the answer is simply historical and you can replace .pipe with .then everywhere.

Answer (score 7):

There is no case where you MUST use `then()` over `pipe()`. You can always choose to ignore the value that `pipe()` will pass in. There *might* be a slight performance hit for using `pipe` -- but it is unlikely to matter.

So it might seem like you could simply always use `pipe()` in both cases. **However**, by using `pipe()`, you are communicating to other people reading your code (including yourself, six months from now) that there is some *importance* to the return value. If you're discarding it, you're violating this semantic construct.

It's like having a function that returns a value that is never used: confusing.

So use `then()` when you should, and `pipe()` when you should...

Comment: I've found a real-life example using the two on K. Scott Allen's blog,
"Experiments In Writing": **[Geolocation, Geocoding, and jQuery Promises](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2012/06/14/geolocation-geocoding-and-jquery-promises.aspx)**: "Then the control logic reads pretty well:"

`$(function () {
    $.when(getPosition())
     .pipe(lookupCountry)
     .then(displayResults);
});`

"Note that pipe is different than then because pipe gives back a new promise."

Answer (score 5):

In fact it turns out that the difference between `.then()` and `.pipe()` has been deemed unnecessary and they have been made to be the same as of jQuery version 1.8.

From [a comment by `jaubourg`](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11010#comment:16) in jQuery's bug tracker [ticket #11010](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11010) "MAKE DEFERRED.THEN == DEFERRED.PIPE LIKE PROMISE/A":

> **In 1.8, we will remove the old then and replace it with current pipe.** But the very sadening consequence is that we'll have to tell people to use the non-standard done, fail and progress, because the proposal doesn't provide simple, EFFICIENT, mean to just add a callback.

<sup>(emphassis mine)</sup>

Comment: Best reference so far, I'm looking for advanced usages.