# jQuery deferred objects: unexpected behavior with .when()s, .then()s and .done()s

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I have a bunch of nested functions returning deferred objects from ajax calls. Here's what my code looks like

```
function makeCalls() {
    var ajaxDfd1 = $.ajax(...);

    ajaxDfd1.then(function() {
        // want to execute after first call
        var ajaxDfd2 =  $.ajax(...);

        ajaxDfd2.done(function() {
            // want to execute after second call
        });

        return ajaxDfd2;
    });

    return ajaxDfd1;
}

makeCalls().done(function() {
    // stuff here was executed early
});
```

But my calls are not being executed in the order I intend them to be. Stuff inside `makeCalls().done()` seems to be called before `ajaxDfd2` is actually done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew I must be getting something wrong, and spent a really long time staring at this:
[When should I use jQuery deferred's "then" method and when should I use the "pipe" method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583783/when-should-i-use-jquery-deferreds-then-method-and-when-should-i-use-the-pip)

Later I realised that I can't do

```
var dfdObj = $.ajax(...);
dfdObj.then(...);

return dfdObj;
```

This doesn't actually return the deferred object. It returns an Ajax object, and since it is a regular object, it is automatically classified as resolved and thus the `.done()` function was being called early. Instead, I need to do this if I want to return a `var`

```
var dfdObj = $.ajax(...).then(...);

return dfdObj;
```

Answer (score 2):

Choc,

You've made an incorrect assumption in your answer; namely that `$.ajax()` returns a "regular object".

This is not correct.

`$.ajax()` returns a jqXHR object, which is a superset of a Promise, ie. it has all of Promise's methods plus others which are specific to AJAX (such as `.abort()`).

If the object returned by `$.ajax()` was not Promise-compatible, then the code in your question would throw an error on trying to execute `makeCalls().done(...)`.

The reason why your `.done()` function executes first it that the function returns the *outer* jqXHR.

Here's a couple of ways to achieve the behaviour you were expecting :

```
function makeCalls() {
    var dfrd = new Deferred();
    $.ajax(...).then(function() {
        $.ajax(...).done(dfrd.resolve);
    });
    return dfrd.promise();
}

makeCalls().done(function(data) {
    // ...
});
```

or

```
function makeCalls(fn) {
    $.ajax(...).then(function() {
        $.ajax(...).done(fn);
    });
}

makeCalls(function(data) {
    // ...
});
```

You could even try :

```
function makeCalls() {
    return $.ajax(...).then(function() {
        return $.ajax(...);
    });
}

makeCalls().done(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: I would not recommend either of the first two versions. The last one is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Bergi, I'm sure you are about to explain why!

Comment: Because the first is overly complicated - `then` (which you are already using) does exactly what you are doing manually; and because the second does not use Deferreds at all but callbacks which was not asked for (Promises were made to supersede CPS)

Comment: @Bergi, OK fair comments though I think it's good for a learner to be exposed to a range of possibilities, each of which still has its place in real-world coding.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works like this:

```
function makeCalls() {
    var ajax1 = $.ajax(…);
    var ajax1and2 = ajax1.then(makeCall2);
    function makeCall2() {
        // want to execute after first call
        var ajax2 =  $.ajax(…);
        ajax2.done(after2);
        function after2() {
            // want to execute after second call
        });
        return ajax2;
    });
    return ajax1;
}

var ajax1 = makeCalls();
ajax1.done(function() {
    // stuff here was executed early
});
```

`ajax1and2` is the result of the `then`/`pipe` call you wanted. A callback on it will wait for the result of `makeCall2` (i.e. the `ajax2`) which waits for `ajax1`. It would be equal to the `after2` callback.

Yet, your `makeCalls` function returns the `ajax1` object (you can see I assigned it to a global `ajax1` variable as well) and both the `makeCall2` and the done-callback will be executed after your first ajax has finished.

So, instead you need to return the `ajax1and2` deferred:

```
function makeCalls() {
    return $.ajax(…).then(function() {
        return $.ajax(…).done(function() {
            // want to execute after second call
        });
    });
}

makeCalls().done(function() {
    // stuff here is now executed after second call as well
});
```