# Whats the difference between the following?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I am confused between the difference between

```
   var getPromise=$.get('/query'),
       postPromise = getPromise.done(function(data){ 
              return $.post('/search',data); 
       });
```

and

```
var getPromise = $.get('/query'); 
var postPromise = getPromise.pipe(function(data){ 
    return $.post('/search',data); 
});
```

Can anyone explain me?

Comment: If this is the whole code, then there is no difference. Otherwise, you might want to read the documentation about `.done` and `.pipe`: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/, http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/.

Comment: `pipe` is a deferred command which returns a new promise that filters the status and values of a deferred through a function. This is replaced by the `then` method as of jquery 1.8.

Comment: Maybe this helps you as well: [When should I use jQuery deferred's “then” method and when should I use the “pipe” method?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9583783/218196).

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for your link. i am reading it right away. can anyone explain me why this question is down voted? i found it confusing so i posted it.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case `postPromise === getPromise`. `.done` returns the same deferred object.

`.pipe` or `.then` creates a new deferred instance.

Comment: Actually `.pipe()` or `.then()` return a new *Promise*, not a *Deferred*, though the distinction is often academic.