# Return resolved promise from rejected callback

Tags: promise

I'm not sure if I'm understanding a certain aspect of promises correctly and I couldn't find what I was looking for after a brief google/SO search.

Can a resolved promise returned to a rejected callback ever fire a resolved method later in the chain? Using jQuery `deferreds` (and it's deprecated `pipe` method) as an example:

```
x = $.Deferred();

x
  .then(null,function() {
     return $.Deferred().resolve();
  })
  .then(function() {
     console.log('resolved');
  },function() {
     console.log('rejected');
  });
```

The above code, logs `rejected`, I would've expected it to log `resolved` because the `Deferred` in the first error callback returns a resolved `promise`.

On the contrary, the same code using `jQuery`'s deprecated `pipe` method logs, as I would've expected `resolved`.

```
x = $.Deferred();

x
  .pipe(null,function() {
    return $.Deferred().resolve();
  })
  .pipe(function() {
     console.log('resolved');
  },function() {
     console.log('rejected');
  });
```

Am I thinking about something wrong by trying to resolve a promise inside a rejected callback?

Comment: Are you missing an `x.reject()` call in your examples?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?! Since ages `x.then === x.pipe` and they act the same!

Comment: possible duplciate of [When should I use jQuery deferred's “then” method and when should I use the “pipe” method?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9583783/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

For anybody who has run into this same thought process, the following page helped me out: https://gist.github.com/domenic/3889970

Specifically:

> ...you can feed the return value of one function straight into another,
>   and keep doing this indefinitely. More importantly, if at any point
>   that process fails, one function in the composition chain can throw an
>   exception, which then bypasses all further compositional layers until
>   it comes into the hands of someone who can handle it with a catch.

It seems jQuery's pipe method was a violation of the Promise's specification.

Comment: It is a violation, and they're fixing it in 3.0 beta. See stackoverflow.com/questions/23744612/problems-inherent-to-jquery-deferred for more details.